# Prove that the sequence is a weakly convergent sequence

Tags: functional-analysis, convergence-divergence, weak-convergence

I am trying to solve the following exercise:

Fix $a,b \in \mathbb{R}^n, 0 < \lambda < 1.$ Define
$$
u_k(x)= \left\{\begin{array}{ccc}
a & \text{if } & \frac jk \leq x < \frac{\lambda(j+1)}{k}\\ 
b & \text{if } & \frac{\lambda(j+1)}{k} \leq x < \frac{j+1}{k}
\end{array} \right.
$$
for $j = 0, \dots, k-1$

Prove $u_k \to \lambda a + (1-\lambda)b$ weakly in $L^2(0,1)$.

I don't know how to do this.

Thank you.

Comment: @Alonsodelfin : Next time you can also use \begin{cases} rather than \begin{array}. You got more or less the same thing.

Comment: @John Great thanks for the tip. And OP, now that the edit makes your question clearer, can you tell us what have you tried? In order to help you we need to know where are you having difficulties

Comment: Call the function which is equal to that constant $u$. You need to show that if $g \in L^2$ then $\int u_k g \to \int ug$. To do this, start by assuming that $g$ is continuous. In that case, for large $k$, $g$ is "essentially constant" on an interval of width $1/k$. Work from there to conclude the result for continuous $g$. Then use a density argument.

Comment: Thanks, I will try. My problem was working with this integral

Comment: I understand the idea, but I don't know how  to write this correctly :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An outline:

First prove that the $u_k$ are bounded in $L^2$, call the bound on their norms $M$. (This is easy, since the $u_k$ are actually pointwise bounded.)

Then, given $g \in L^2$ and $\varepsilon > 0$, find a piecewise constant function $s$ with $\| g - s \|_{L^2} < \varepsilon/2M$. (This can be done because simple functions are dense and the Lebesgue measure is regular.) Now choose $K$ large enough that if $k \geq K$ then $s$ is constant on each of the pieces of $u_k$. Use this and the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality to finish the proof.